# Error 1053 while trying to restart/stop Tomcat 5.0.30 (installed as a windows service)

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services

I have Tomcat 5.0.30 installed as a Windows service. This service is starting perfectly fine. However when I try to restart or stop the service from the Windows services console, I'm getting the following error:

*

> **Could not stop Tomcat service on Local Computer. Error 1053: The
>   service did not respond to the start
>   or the control request in a timely
>   fashion**

*

I recently upgraded to Tomcat 5.0.30 from 5.0.28 and earlier this was working perfectly fine. Its the latest version that's causing this issue. Google wasn't of much help.

Does anybody have any clue as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Are you positive that you have removed all references to the old version. I found a similar problem once when the service was referring to the old version. I had to uninstall it and reinstall the service to pick up the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try starting tomcat from command line and then press control + C and see if it stops. I guess its hanging that is why giving error. If that is the case than try again by switching on logging at DEBUG level and see if anything in the logs. Still no clue then you can take thread dump and analyze to see what threads are hanging.