# Stop Apache Tomcat when web application stops

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

**Scenario:**

Apache Tomcat 6.0 is started as a service on Windows Server 2008 R2 using a wrapper (`org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperStartStop`) which uses `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap`. In course of the Tomcat startup one web application is also started.
This web application needs to connect to a remote database and check the connection. It retries to connect a couple of times if the database is not available and then shutdown after x tries.

**Problem:**

I need to stop Apache Tomcat after the web app exits when the database connection is not available.

**Possible solutions:**

- Stop Apache Tomcat from within the web application (already tried the shutdown port which did not work because the connection was refused - with a standalone Java application it worked)
- Call an external Java application from within the web application
- Configure Apache Tomcat to shut down if the only web application shuts down - I could not find a way to do that

Any ideas? Maybe a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.exit(0)` from within your webapp will shut down the Tomcat instance if there is no security manager configured.

Works from a standalone server, not sure whether it works when running as a Windows service.

Edit: though you might want to read this: [Calling System.exit() in Servlet's destroy() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546097/calling-system-exit-in-servlets-destroy-method)

Answer (score 1):

When Tomcat is started, you essentially invoke `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap::main` with parameter `start`. To stop Tomcat, invoke the same class/method with command `stop`. You should not need another Java process for that, just call the `main` method statically.

See the Javadoc:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap.html

If you don't want the dependency on Tomcat libs, just do some reflection magic.

Comment: I was thinking about that already, but how do I get the Bootstrap object when I am within the webb application? Outside the web application I dont know that the db connection does not work.

Comment: As I mentioned, just use static main method - org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(new String[] {"stop"})

Comment: From within the running web app it does not work! The Bootstrap object can be called but an exception ("Connection refused") is thrown. I know that it works from a different Java process, but I wanted to avoid having to call an external application.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm pretty sure this is a bad way of doing it, but like you, I have been unable to come up with a better solution.

```
try{
    MBeanServer server = MBeanUtils.createServer();
    ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Service,serviceName=Catalina");
    server.invoke(name, "stop", new Object[0], new String[0]);
} catch (Exception) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will basically tell Catalina to kill itself.