# Cannot close applet in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, libvlc, vlcj

I have an applet that runs VLCJ (http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) - basically embedding a VLC player in an applet. 
When running in eclipse, it runs well but I cannot close the debugging applet-window or terminate it somehow. I wonder, why is this? Is there anything in the code that prevents it from stopping debugging? I have to restart eclipse in order to make it quit. Im quite sure you dont need to add destroy() to enable closing of the debugging window.

Thanks

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;


public class Main extends JApplet {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    /* entry point */
    public void init() {
        String file = "110825-155446.wmv";    // only 2-3 seconds clip for minimum storage      
        runVideo(file);
    }

    /* runs the video file */
    public void runVideo(String file) {

        setSize(400,300);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        Canvas vs = new Canvas();
        add(vs,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);

        MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

        EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = factory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(factory.newVideoSurface(vs));

        mediaPlayer.playMedia(file);
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is at this code snippet part:

```
try {
    Thread.currentThread().join();
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

It blocks the application from closing since it doesn't want to return to the system. `Thread.join()` makes the current thread waits for another thread to complete, basically it waits forever.

To improve it, you can do like this (as in http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/MinimalMp3Player):

```
mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
  public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    System.exit(0);
  }
  public void error(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    System.exit(1);
  }
});
mediaPlayer.playMedia(args[0]);
Thread.currentThread().join();
```

However, we cannot use `System.exit()` method in a Java servlet code (or even applet code) as it can shutdown the JVM used by the code which may be needed by other Java application/servlet/applet codes. See [Alternatives to System.exit(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790/alternatives-to-system-exit1), [Calling System.exit() in Servlet's destroy() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546097/calling-system-exit-in-servlets-destroy-method)